# Overriding to_s method in ruby

Tags: ruby

All classes in ruby inherits from  object class having to_s method and when you try to print an object this to_s method is called on the object which converts its value to string.But in my below code i have overridden  the to_s method still its printing that non-readable data.Why so

```
class Employee
  attr_reader :name,:salary

  def name=(value)
    if value == " "
      raise "Name can not be empty"
    end
    @name=value
    end

   def salary=(value)
     if value <0
       raise "Salary can not be negative"
     end
     @salary=value
   end 

   def print_pay_stub
     puts "Name : #{@name}"
     pay_for_period= (@salary/365)*30
     puts"Pay this period: #{pay_for_period}"
   end

   def to_s
          puts ("I am a hi man")
   end

end

ob=Employee.new
ob.name="akash"
ob.salary=900000
ob.print_pay_stub()
puts ob
```

**Output:**

```
Name : akash
Pay this period: 73950
I am a hi man
#<Employee:0x2b9bb28>
```

It prints what's in overridden method to_s but why that extra string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def to_s
  "I am a hi man"
end
```

You need to return the value, not output it.

Comment: Yes it worked so how can we conclude the behaviour ,if we override a method but  provide different return types then does ruby executes both.In my problem overridden to_s returns nil  so i guess buth are executed is it so

Comment: @thinkingmonster "Ruby executes both" makes no sense. Of course Ruby will execute both statements, sequentially. See the linked duplicate for an explanation of why returning a non-string from `to_s` causes `puts` to fallback to the default behavior.